# Click on text object it covers full canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I am using fabric js for video streaming. when i add fabric textbox on canvas and click outside textbox object textbox element cover full canvas as i attached in image and it unable to allow me enter text.

this is the code i am using for add text box on cavas.

```
oText = new fabric.Textbox('', {
        width: 150,
        top: 50,
        left: 50,
        fontSize: 16,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fill: brushColor,
        selectable:false
       // textBackgroundColor: '#0A97FF',
    });
```

How can i restrict element to cover it and allow me to enter text at any size of text element
Sorry for my bad english.
[see my image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB0p1.png)

Comment: It's not textbox, may be that is the image/video element getting selected.

Comment: From your description, it really looks like you just select an underlying video when you click outside the textbox -> the video gets brought forward -> the textbox is not clickable as it is now underneath the video. Try setting `selectable: false` to your video, or `preserveObjectStacking: true` to your canvas.